# Capturing and saving objects with fabric js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I'm using fabric JS to build out a canvas where users can then add any image wanted to this canvas, my question at hand is, how can i save that canvas or the positions of these images so if the user moves to canvas2 its a empty canvas but if user returns to the first canvas those images get loaded up in the last location they moved them?

Should i be using the toJSON() method fabric.js has to get the JSON data of those images then save data in a localStorage but how would i load it after? or is there a more efficient way with fabric.js?

Comment: If the user is in the same web session you probably don't need to store on localStorage, keep it in memory, serialize with `fabric.Canvas#toObject` and deserialize with `fabric.Canvas#loadFromJSON`. If you want to store it server side, you can use `fabric.Canvas#toJSON()`. Also SVG serialization/deserialization is an option. I recommend fabric's introduction on [serialization](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization) and [deserialization](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#deserialization)

Comment: Okay, I was using toJSON but not storing data server side probably the reason why it wasnt working on my end. Thank you for clearing that up for me!